# Powershell - get a list of all SharePoint Group for all web application - output to csv

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

So, I'm trying to write a script to iterate through all web apps, extract the groups & members from each site collection/child site and output to CSV.
I used Konstantin Vlasenko's [function](https://vlasenko.org/2014/05/07/sharepoint-2013-powershell-how-to-get-user-permissions-report/)  to extract group information.  Works like a charm!
What I'm trying to do now is get this to get all web apps, get all webs and then get all sites.  Here's what I have so far but......so far all I get in my array is the code exported to CSV.  I'm off somewhere.  Can you see what I'm missing?

...
{

CLS

$groups = @()
$webapps = Get-SPWebApplication
$sites = $webapps | Get-SPSite
$webs = $sites | Get-SPWeb
    function Get-SPPermissionsRoles($web, $recursive){
    foreach($webapp in $webapps)
    {
        #$sites = Get-SPSite $webapps
        foreach($site in $sites)
        {
            {
              $webs | Get-SPUser | % { New-Object PSObject -Property {
                $grpobject = Add-Member -Name UserLogin = $*.UserLogin

                $grpobject = Add-Member -Name 'Roles given explicitly' = $*.Roles
                $grpobject = Add-Member -Name 'Roles given via groups' = $*.Groups | %{$*.Roles}
                $grpobject = Add-Member -Name Groups = $_.Groups
                $grpobject = Add-Member -Name Url = $web.Url
                $groups += $grpobject
                }

```
          }  
          if($recursive) { $web.Webs | % { Get-SPPermissionsRoles $_ $recursive }   }  
        }  
    }  
}  
}
```

Get-SPPermissionsRoles $webs $true | Export-Csv -Path "E:\Temp\Roles.csv"
$groups | Export-Csv "E:\temp\groups.csv"

}
...

Answer (score 0):

Hope these articles are helpful to you:

[SharePoint PowerShell to Get All Users in Farm](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/12/get-all-users-of-sharepoint-site-collection-web-app-farm.html)

[Export SharePoint Users and Groups to Excel using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/export-sharepoint-users-and-groups-to-excel-using-powershell.html)